Can Nakayama Lemma apply to complex
Let $R$ be a Noetherian commutative local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Consider a complex of finitly generated projective $R$-mod (so it is free)
$$0\rightarrow P_1\rightarrow P_2\rightarrow P_3\rightarrow \cdots.$$
Suppose
$$0\rightarrow P_1\otimes A/\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow P_2\otimes A/\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow P_3\otimes A/\mathfrak{m}\rightarrow \cdots$$
is exact as vector space.
Can Nakayama Lemma shows that the original complex is also exact.
When there exists $i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $P_k=0$ for $k>i$, this result can be deduced from induction on $i$ and Nakayama Lemma. But if there are infinite nonzero objects, I cannot judge whether it is correct or not.
